# How to import libraries that are not on npm registry in a webpack-built application?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, npm

I have a react application written in typescript that uses webpack to compile. So far, I could import libraries through the `import` keyword from node_modules.

However, there are a few libraries I would like to use that are not on the npm registry. So I can't do a npm install of these libraries. For example, Papa Parse is one of those that I can't quite find its npm package. They usually only provide a minified js file which I can't just import into my Typescript file.

For applications that uses webpack to build, how can I use libraries that are not on the npm registry in my code?

Comment: You may have to shim them in webpack....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anything that doesn't have an `npm` package, you'll have to download the file and put it somewhere in your project - I'd recommend putting it in a directory called `vendor` or `lib`.

The `import` statement can use a relative path to the module you want to use, so it should be straightforward, e.g. if you put your third-party module in `vendor/some-lib.js`, you would import it with:

```
// src/foo.js
import './../vendor/some-lib';
```

If you want to get fancy, you can use `resolve.alias` in your webpack config so that you never have to work out the relative path.

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

// ...
resolve: {
  alias: {
    vendor: path.resolve(__dirname, 'vendor')
  }
},

// src/foo.js
import 'vendor/some-lib';
```

Comment: I tried importing the library through relative path but somehow I still can't access the library. It's like if I imported jQuery, I still can't use `jQuery()` or `$` in my code. After importing the lib at the top of the code, what else do I have to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can install git-hosted libraries like this:

```
npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:mholt/PapaParse.git#4.3.0
```

Note that everything after the hash has to be either a commit hash or a tag. I got 4.3.0 from here: https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/releases

If you omit the hash, you'll get the most recent version, but keep in mind every time someone does a fresh `npm install` in your codebase there's a chance of them pulling down a version with breaking changes.

Comment: Cool. This certainly looks like a nice technique! I didn't know this is possible! I'm gonna try this out!

Comment: :] I should add this part "git@github.com:mholt/PapaParse.git" is from the ssh clone link

Comment: You may just as well be able to use the https:// link `https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse.git#4.3.0` ...though I've never tried it myself

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot import them then you can use require on them and webpack will build them into bundle.

```
require("PapaParse");
```

Note:- if you are resolving js files from webpack then you can use simply

`import "papaparse"`

Comment: But if I just do a `require("PapaParse")`, how is webpack going to know which path to resolve for the library?

Comment: There are many ways to require an file depends on if the file is an module or you just need to include it in your build. [Read more about webpack require](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html)